# Multiline in SVG <title> (Internet Explorer) | Linebreak, tabulations

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg, tooltip

I would like to add a multiline tooltip to my SVG path using the `<title>` tag.

It works perfectly in Chrome, but the linebreak characters I have tried result in a space in Internet Explorer.

Also in Internet Explorer, the multiline works in the `title=""` attribute.

The below code snippet has the same muliline tootltip on a svg and on a button. To be run in IE.

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
    <path d="M45 0 L15 80 L75 80 Z">
        <title>test&#xA;test</title>
        <!--<title>test&#xA;test</title>-->
        <!--<title>test&#10;test</title>-->
        <!--<title>test&#13;test</title>-->
    </path>
</svg>
<div><button title="test&#xA;test">It works here</button><div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the IE browser, using `<br>` tag to add a line break in the SVG element; In the Microsoft Edge and Chrome browser using the `&#xA;` add a line break.

Code as below:

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
    <path d="M45 0 L15 80 L75 80 Z">
        <title>test&#xA;<br>test</title>
        <!--<title>test&#xA;test</title>-->
        <!--<title>test&#10;test</title>-->
        <!--<title>test&#13;test</title>-->
    </path>
</svg>
<div><button title="test&#xA;test">It works here</button></div>
```

Output like this:

IE browser:

[image]

Chrome Browser:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In ReactJS this is worked for me:

```
<svg><title>text1+{'\n'}text2</title></svg>
```